# psycopg2 gives error while installing in macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Tags: python, django, postgresql, macos, psycopg2

I'm trying to install psycopg2 in my django project. it's gives me this error. I already install (psycopg2 binary, pillow & other packages these are working fine). I just reinstalled my macOS & Xcode. I'm using python 3.8.3 & Django 3.0.5 and Homebrew 2.4.5 and my PostgreSQL 12.3

```
Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

 
 command:
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c
 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
 '"'"'/private/var/folders/hj/q_49d8351l11gj135qs6c01r0000gn/T/pip-install-zr_qlm_k/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';
 __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/hj/q_49d8351l11gj135qs6c01r0000gn/T/pip-install-zr_qlm_k/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
 '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
 '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
 install --record
 /private/var/folders/hj/q_49d8351l11gj135qs6c01r0000gn/T/pip-record-rc16k7t9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/psycopg2
 
ld: library not found for -lssl
     clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
     error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
     ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c
 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
 '"'"'/private/var/folders/hj/q_49d8351l11gj135qs6c01r0000gn/T/pip-install-zr_qlm_k/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';
 __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/hj/q_49d8351l11gj135qs6c01r0000gn/T/pip-install-zr_qlm_k/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
 '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
 '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
 install --record
 /private/var/folders/hj/q_49d8351l11gj135qs6c01r0000gn/T/pip-record-rc16k7t9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/psycopg2
 Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: If you have psycopg2-binary installed why install psycopg2?

Answer (score 4):

Instead use psycopg2-binary which will install perfectly.

`pip install psycopg2-binary`

Comment: So when you run that command? What do you do next? reinstalling the packages or just continue?

Comment: This works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my mac m1 and I resolved it with

`brew install postgresql`

after that install

`pip3 install psycopg2`

and it works fine